# Empty payload in Auth0 JWT Authorization tokens

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm currently developing a React Single Page Application (SPA) that uses Auth0 for authentication. I have successfully implemented login and logout features. However, when requesting an Authorization JWT with getTokenSilently(), the tokens I am given have an empty payload when decoded. For now I'm just logging it to my browsers console in a local test environment. For example:
eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtdzAxODFhcXNobGw1MDMzbC51cy5hdXRoMC5jb20vIn0..thF3uZU-GjTkcNVo.EQawZb4Ebgww3ZT-Pa73eoJ62qLQ0HSIswroGiecQZHGdZLw-953s6asccnawPD9HwSObZ3JcsbP8HAFarNf2p5Zrr2sbp4QvGxfB6RgpWZTxEK2Tntu7X7w9i_7z2Iw8c_3lUZPnHe0_4OLaHnPyetzk8_Pqm2-JcELrNIwvRPTD1QmdMsbyvz6_u9kANS181FH7wSyxtt5UP5Hu_BnQ3lmEQhB5yMvL42PjaAsoaclxEdQ0EQmcCRdnNrQVqnKadZumwvs2jQ-A-onQI9lL3rhlPEktJP8Sy-UyhRv-U_Az6MmY4D92-VRD_AjXhXLggV7iXMS8hZM9N_cDDCA5skg.Fuf3LqTHjNuCZj_fS8P8HQ
**Issue Details:**
Technology Stack: ReactJS with Auth0 SPA SDK
Auth0 SDK Version: @auth0/auth0-react": "^2.1.0",
"@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "2.0.3",
Browser: Tried on multiple browsers including Chrome and Safari, and also in Incognito mode
Error Messages: None
**Steps to Reproduce:**
User logs in via Auth0.
React App retrieves the token.
React App writes writes the token to console for debugging purposes.

Code Snippets:

[auth-provider.js](https://gist.github.com/jrolo-ris/17884f5041d3a28e674ac07da7fcde36)
[app.js](https://gist.github.com/jrolo-ris/12406b0409190893fc2cc987f01481da)

**What I have Tried:**
Logged in and out multiple times, also in incognito mode in case of cacheing.
Checked Auth0 Dashboard logs for any signs of errors or irregularities.
Ensured that the Auth0Client object is initialized with an audience, which is an API that I crated in the Auth0 Dashboard.
Reviewed and followed Auth0 SPA SDK documentation - though I am a beginner and most likely have something configured wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an audience parameter to get the access token as a JWT. For example:

```
return (
  <Auth0Provider
    domain={domain}
    clientId={clientId}
    authorizationParams={{
      audience: audience,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    }}
    useRefreshTokens={true}
    onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
  >
    <>{props.children}</>
  </Auth0Provider>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Matt!

I think I have the audience defined - 

I defined the audience when I created the client:

const auth0Client = new Auth0Client({
  domain: (my domain),
  clientId: (my clientID),
  cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
  audience: 'https://api.tailor.video/api/v1',
  authorizationParams: {
    redirect_uri: auth0Config.base_url + paths.auth.auth0.callback,
  },
});

And directly in the function:

      const token = await auth0Client.getTokenSilently({
        audience: 'https://api.tailor.video/api/v1',
        scope: "openid profile",
    });

Comment: You need to move the `audience` to the `authorizationParams` section.

Comment: Thanks - yes I needed to move it into the array. Thanks!